# Правильно ли я поставила знаки препинания? Какое предложение составлено лучше? Заранее благодарна

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

1) Двухсторонний. Белая сторона для магнитов и для рисования маркерами на водной основе, черная для рисования мелом.

2) Имеет 2 стороны: белая  – под магниты, водные маркеры и черная – под мел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Двухсторонний. Белая сторона – для магнитов и для рисования маркерами на водной основе, черная – для рисования мелом.

Имеет *две* стороны: белая – под магниты *и* водные маркеры, черная – под мел.

**Первое предложение более подробное и, на мой взгляд, составлено лучше второго.**